# CSS is not rendering with HTML file in Django

Tags: html, css, django

I've been trying to link up my css with the HTML code, but CSS is not working in DJANGO!
I'm sharing all the screenshots of my code!
Hope anyone can help me out with this.
Thanks in advance!

```css
h2{
    color: blue;
}

.heading {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>MY PROFILE</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/index.css'  %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        WELCOME HERE!
        <h2 class="heading">This is CSS</h2> 
        
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the file the CSS is in and maybe code from python if it applies to your attempt at linking it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the static file base directory in settings.py?

```
import os
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

Comment: i just did that and thank you! it resolved my issue!